# Auth0 login Authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, auth0

I registered a user in Auth0 to login (in the Users option of the dashboard)
I was using the following code to authenticate the user (with a html form with username and password)

```
public login(username: string, password: string): void {
    this.auth0.redirect.loginWithCredentials({
      connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
      username,
      password
    }, err => {
      if (err) return alert(err.description);
    });
  }
```

and it worked perfectly.
However, due to the deprecation of redirect.loginWithCredentials, I want to use client.login but it is not working. This is my code

```
this.auth0.client.login({
      realm: 'Database',
      grant_type: 'http://auth0.com/oauth/grant-type/password-realm',
      username,
      password,
      scope: 'openid profile',
    }, err => {
      if (err) return alert(err.description);
  });
```

I think that the problem is the name of the realm. What is the name of the realm to use the Users that I created in Auth0?

Thanks for all

Comment: Be helpful to know what version of auth0.js library you are using. Did you try  putting the name of your DB connection as realm value ie. Username-Password-Authentication   (putting a comment here instead of an answer as I have not explicitly checked)

Comment: Thanks it is v 8.8.0

Comment: Hi, did my answer below resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi, did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be set to the connection name. See [here](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant#realm-support).

In your case, try setting to `Username-Password-Authentication`.

From the docs:

> Set the new request parameter realm to the realm the user belongs.
>   This maps to a connection in Auth0. For example, if you have
>   configured a database connection for your internal employees and you
>   have named the connection employees, then use this value.